# How to get a readable stream to 'close'

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm getting a readable stream (`require('stream').Readable`) from a library I'm using*.

In a general sense, how can I close this (any) readable stream once all data is consumed?  I'm seeing the `end` event, but the `close` event is never received.

Tried: `.close()` and `destroy()` don't seem to be avail anymore on `require('stream').Readable`, while they were avail on `require('fs') streams`.

I believe the above is causing some erratic behavior under load. I.e.: running out of file descriptors, mem leaks, etc, so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

*) [x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray). Under the covers it uses [enstore](https://github.com/juliangruber/enstore), which uses an adapted `require('stream').Readable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readable streams typically don't emit `close` (they emit `end`). The `close` event is more for Writable streams to indicate that an underlying file descriptor has been closed for example.

There is no need to manually close a Readable stream once all of the data has been consumed, it ends automatically (this is done when the stream implementation calls `push(null)`).

Of course if the stream implementation isn't cleaning up any resources it uses behind the scenes, then that is a bug and should be filed on the appropriate project's issue tracker.